# Angular.js Select with ngOptions: Label the optgroup

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I just started to play with Angular.js and have a question about ngOptions: Is it possible to label the optgroup?

Lets assume 2 objects - cars and garages.

```js
cars = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Diablo", "color": "red", "garageId": 1},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Countach", "color": "white", "garageId": 1},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Clio", "color": "silver", "garageId": 2},
    ...
]
garages = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Super Garage Deluxe"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Toms Eastside"},
    ...
]
```

With this code I got nearly the result I want:

```js
ng-options = "car.id as car.name + ' (' + car.color + ')' group by car.garageId for car in cars"
```

Result in the select:

```
-----------------
1
 Diablo (red)
 Countach (white)
 Firebird (red)
2
 Clio (silver)
 Golf (black)
3
 Hummer (silver)
-----------------
```

But I want to label the optgroups like "Garage 1", "Garage 2", ... or even better display the name of the garage and not just the garageId.

The [angularjs.org documentation for select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) says nothing about labels for the optgroup, but I would like to extend the group by part of ngOptions like `group by car.garageId as 'Garage ' + car.garageId` or `group by car.garageId as getGarageName(car.garageId)` - *which sadly is not working*.

My only solution so far is to add a new property "garageDisplayName" to the car objects and store there the id + garage name and use that as group by parameter. But I don't want to update all cars whenever a garage name is changed.

Is there a way to label the optgroups with ngOptions, or should I use ngRepeat in that case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can just call `getGarageName()` in the `group by` without using an `as`...

```
ng-options="car.id as car.name + ' (' + car.color + ')' group by getGarageName(car.garageId) for car in cars"
```

Instead of storing the garage id in each car, you might want to consider storing a reference to the garage object in the garages array. That way you can change the garage name and there is no need to change each car. And the `group by` simply becomes...

`group by car.garage.name`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I always tried it with the `as` part instead of just write the expression I want to display. :) So it's also possible to do `group by 'Garage ' + car.garageId`.

Comment: And as you suggested I considered to store the reference of the garage instead the id and ended with this: `group by car.garage.name + ' - ' + car.garage.id` _(garage name is not unique)_ which indeed is simpler.